# Relative Paths, etc. on an Apache server

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, relative-path

I'm really stuck here.

I have 2 issues at once:

First, my site is stored (both on local development and on live server), in a subdirectory.. as I'm working on multiple sites. i.e.

```
/Sites/www.mysite.com/(site files here)
```

When I'm referring to files in my web pages, I want to refer to, say, my `/images` directory without hard-coding every occurrence as `/www.mysite.com/images/myfile.jpg`

Is there a way to simply redefine how the leading "/" gets interpreted by the server?

Question two, concerning PHP mod_rewrite

I have this set of rewrite rules.  The objective is to turn www.mysite.com/faq into www.mysite.com/index.php?page="faq"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mysite.com
RewriteRule (.*) mysite.com/$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /mysite.com/index.php?site=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /mysite.com/index.php?site=$1
```

I don't have a problem when a url gets passed in the 2nd-to-last format (as the example above).  However, if the trailing "/" is added: `www.mysite.com/faq/`, my external script references break: (such as `src=js/script.js`)...

Comment: These are two separate questions and should probably be separated into separate posts.

Comment: The first is a non-question, relative paths of that kind are handled by the browser, referring to `/images/img.jpg` will work fine as long as the server has a domain attached to `/Sites/www.mysite.com/`

Comment: I think the slash interpretation is given by DocumentRoot variable in VirtualServer configuration file. should be DocumentRoot "/Sites/www.mysite.com/" or "/Sites/mysite.com/www/"

Comment: Try using the `[L]` (last) modifier in your rules to tell Apache to stop processing other rules if one is matched. Might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To question no. 1:**

Apache is interpreting leading slash according to `DocumentRoot` or `Alias` values

So if you want to make your life easier, create `VirtualServer` with this

```
DocumentRoot "/Sites/www.mysite.com"
```

[Apache documentation: DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot)

or `Alias`

```
Alias /mysite /Sites/www.mysite.com
```

[Apache documentation: Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)

or use path-relative addressing.

**To question no.2:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mysite.com
RewriteRule (.*) mysite.com/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /mysite.com/index.php?site=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /mysite.com/index.php?site=$1 [L]
```

according to `netcoder` advice.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: don't put a leading slash, and the path will be relative to your calling script's file location.

so if the calling script is in the directory

/www.mysite.com/myscript.php

and you use a filepath in your script of

images/myfile.jpg

this should work for what you are doing, and lead to

/www.mysite.com/images/myfile.jpg